# Okay to call a file core.foo?

Tags: linux, unix, filenames

On Unix-like operating systems, one should never call a file `core` because it might be overwritten by a core dump, so that name is de facto reserved for use by the operating system.

But what about with an extension, like `core.c`? It seems to me this should be perfectly okay; `core` and `core.c` are two distinct names.

Is the above correct, and names like `core.foo` are okay? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: At least on Linux, the system administrator can use `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to configure the names of core files, which can include the name of the program (`%e`) and/or host (`%h`) among other substitutions.   Some people might set it to something like `core.%e` and if a program named `foo` should crash, it will dump core to `core.foo`.  Maybe not hugely likely, but probably safer to name your file something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On Unix-like operating systems,

Ie. on a system conforming to [the single UNIX Specification](http://www.unix.org/version4/overview.html) (or just to [POSIX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). Or on a system belonging to the [unix family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix).

> one should never call a file core because it might be overwritten by a core dump, so that name is de facto reserved for use by the operating system.

No. I do not think there is a specification that specifies that core dumps are going into a file named "core". It's all "implementation defined", from [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_117):

> 3.117 Core File
>
> A file of unspecified format that may be generated when a process terminates abnormally.

If coredump is created, where is it created, how and what the contents are, it's all up to implementation. [Freebsd creates a file named [executable_name.core](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?core(5)) for ages. So not "on unix-like operating systems". Your sentence could be made valid by changing the beginning to:

> On a *linux system with kernel version lower then 2.6 or 2.4.21* one should never call a file "core", because...

Kernel 2.6 and 2.4.21 is more then 15 years old. Newer kernels have `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` that allow specifying the filename and location and even a process to run on a coredump. So if you are working with such archaic kernel version lower then 2.6 or 2.4.21 (or the content of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` is naively set to `core`), then yes, you should be careful when creating a file named "core".

In today's world, that behavior doesn't matter at all, on most linux distributions `systemd-coredump` takes care of that and creates coredumps in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`.

> But what about with an extension, like core.c?

It's ok - `core` and `core.c` are different filenames. Dot is not a special character, it's just a character like anything else, `core.c` differs from `core` as much as `core12` or `coreAB` does...

> Is the above correct,

Yes.

> and names like core.foo are okay?

Are okay.

> Or am I missing anything?

No idea, but if you are, I surely hope you will find it.

Comment: Very nice writeup.